# How to make md-sidenav-container full height of div in an angular4 app?

Tags: angular, material-design

I have an angular4 app and am using the angular materials framework https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples. I want to make the md-sidenav-container stretch the whole height of the div without covering up the header. I have attached the fullscreen directive, which causes the sidenav to fill the whole height of the screen thus covering up the header component. This is not what I want. The images show the sidenav stretch above the header, as well as another attempt where it stops at the header but does not stretch to the bottom. I want it to stretch all the way up to the header and all the way down to the bottom of the screen. How do I accomplish this?
Thanks!

Html

```
<div class="bar">
  <md-sidenav-container class="example-sidenav-fab-container">
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true" align="end">
    <!--<button md-mini-fab class="example-fab" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">-->
      <!--<md-icon>add</md-icon>-->
    <!--</button>-->
    <div class="example-scrolling-content">
      <ul>
        <li>Recommendations</li>
        <li>Events</li>
        <li>Settings</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </md-sidenav>
  <button md-mini-fab class="example-fab" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
    <md-icon>add</md-icon>
  </button>
</md-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

Css

```
md-sidenav-container
  :background-color white
  :float right
  :width 300px
  :height 400px

md-sidenav
  :background-color $light-blue


//.example-sidenav-fab-container
//  width: 300px
//  height: 400px
  //border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)


.example-sidenav-fab-container md-sidenav
  max-width: 300px

.example-sidenav-fab-container md-sidenav
  display: flex
  overflow: visible

.example-scrolling-content
  overflow: auto


.example-fab
  position: absolute
  right: 20px
  bottom: 10px

.bar
  :height 100%
```

[image: Not what I want]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have found this workaround that works ok
**HTML**

```
<md-sidenav-container id="container" fullscreen >
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
 top: 64px !important;
}

@media(max-width: 599px) {
  #container {
    top: 56px !important;
  }
}
```

top has to have the same height of your toolbar. Remember that the standard Angular Material toolbar height becomes smaller when the width is less than 600px .

Comment: It works, although I agree it works ok, there has to be a better solution for this out there.

Comment: The answer below by @bdiloreto is a better solution!

Comment: In the latest version of Material design (at the moment of writing), you can set `fixedInViewport="true"` and `fixedTopGap="72"` or whatever value is relevant, see https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api

Answer (score 25):

I struggled with the same problem. The solution of setting the top to 64px did not work for me.

I found two different solutions.

1. The first solution uses flexbox.  Put the `md-toolbar` and `md-sidenav-container` inside of a div with `height: 100%` and uses `display: flex` with `flex-direction: column`.
2. Alternatively, and this solution may actually do the same thing, you can leave the `md-toolbar` and `md-sidenav-container` items at the root level, and then make the `md-sidenav-container` have a `height: calc(100% - 64px)` where the height of the toolbar is 64px.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I have a navigation that acts like a frame around my whole site, it has a top-nav, sidenav that slides out on mobile. And this is what I used for it. Also within it's content area, on some of our pages we have advanced search forms that also slide out. So this is a sidenav-container nested within another sidenav-container's content area.  Again, the same problem arises on pges where the content does not push past the fold or bottom of the viewport we use this same code there. REmember that if your navigation is smaller like mine (45px) don't just plug in 65px lol

Comment: None of the suggestions works. However, the accepted answer does. Sorry to say ... ;)

Comment: I set `flex-grow: 1` on the sidenav-container

Answer (score 9):

```
html, body, material-app, mat-sidenav-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: u mean classes `.material-app, .mat-sidenav-container` ?

Comment: The only one answer that really works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This seems to work if the sidenav occupies 100% of the height of the page, but when there is a toolbar and the sidenav is under it, this style makes the height too big: 100% + the height of the toolbar, so you end up with a vertical scrollbar